# Where do page layouts fit into the react (redux) presentational vs container pattern?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've read Dan Abramov's article on [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0). In it he explains a pattern where you separate components into components that handle *how things look*, and components that handle *how things work*.

I'm trying to build my react app according to this architecture, but have run into a problem. Let's say I have a page `UserProfile`. It contains a collection of presentational components, and needs various data sources. I need to define how this page looks, which I'll call `UserProfile`.

**Page as presentational component**

Do I then build the `UserProfile` component as a presentational component, and wire up all the data sources by wrapping each presentational component in the appropriate container?

```
<UserProfile> // presentational
  <AvatarData> // container
    <Avatar /> // presentational
  </AvatarData>
  <CommentData> // container
    <Comments /> // presentational
  </CommentData>
</UserProfile>
```

Because this would not allow multiple data sources for a single component and it can cause your code for the containers to become rather repetitive.

**Page as container component**

Or, [In the real-world example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/src/containers/UserPage.js) in the redux repo a different approach is used, where the container also defines a layout (rather minimalistic though). This allows you to define all the data sources a page needs in one place, and allows you to use multiple data sources for a single component. However, defining style in this component would be a no-no, which works if your page is very minimalistic, but falls apart if it becomes more complicated.

So my question is: how should complicated pages (both in style, data and behaviour) be defined when using this pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't over-think the "container" and "presentational" aspects too much.  It's a useful distinction, but there's no hard-and-fast rule saying you *must* break apart components in an absolutely strict way.  It's totally fine to put some layout and presentational rendering in a container component, and it's totally fine to render container components inside a presentational component.

Comment: Yeah I guess I was overthinking it a bit. I've now split up the page in a container and a presentational part, and I'm expecting to just figure out what works for me along the way. Thanks for the advice!